# Nhibernate session.BeginTransaction() vs. transaction.Begin()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions

My question is related to use of nhibernate transactions

Is the `transaction.Begin()` below a problem? or just redundant?

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    transaction.Begin();
    action();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Bookmark this : http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged

Comment: Reading Ayende is always good ... but in this case doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After checking the source, `transaction.Begin()` is in fact redundant - a harmless no-op.

[link to source](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=n7K0oYOSBPGZigiPfUQ4BtbTBz4&cid=AS5gcGIrOlA&s=&browser=Default&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=true#L108)

Answer (score 3):

`beginTransaction` as it states begins a transaction,

on the other hand

`session.Transaction` will return the current active transaction if null will create one.

The NHibernate session tracks the current active (not committed or
rolled back) transaction.

If you call `ISession.Transaction` when no transaction has yet been
created yet during the life time of the session, the session will
create a new transaction object at that point in time, but won't begin
it yet. When you call `ISession.BeginTransaction`, the session will see
if their is already a transaction object that has been created before,
but not yet completed. If so, it will return this transaction object.
If not, it will create a new transaction object, begin it and store a
reference to this new object.

On transaction completion, the transaction object notifies the session
to which it belongs that it has completed, on which the session will
release its reference to the transaction object. Any following call to
`ISession.Transaction` or `ISession.BeginTransaction` will then cause the
creation of a new transaction object.

NHibernate does not support reuse of transaction objects for more than
one transaction (this behaviour may be different from Hibernate, which
does seem to support reuse of transaction objects).

Refer [this](http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged) document.

Comment: A little confusing...so beginTransaction only creates a new transaction if there no current transaction in the session, otherwise returns the existing one?  So what effect does the subsequent transaction.Begin() have in this case?  Is it a no-op?